Flutter: GetX vs Riverpod inner implementation regarding streams usage
In GetX we have Reactive State Management and Simple State Management. Names are, IMHO, a bit misleading, as they are both reactive in some sense, but the first uses streams, and the second uses callbacks. The second was declared to be more performance-friendly. Examples:
First (with streams)
class Controller extends GetxController {
  var count = 0.obs;

  increment() {
    count.value++;
  }
}

It should be consumed using Obx or GetX widgets.
Second (with callbacks)
class Controller extends GetxController {
  int counter = 0;
  void increment() {
    counter++;
    update(); 
  }
}

It should be consumed using the GetBuilder widget alone.
Now, the question is:
Are there both stream/callback approaches in Riverpod?
Can you provide analog examples of the above?
